# Positioning small divs exactly at the center of big one. Getting size of div in CSS

Tags: css, css-position

So, this is how my div looks like (i'm talking about this blue rhomb with 4 white squares):
[image]

I want to put this white squares exactly at the center of sides of their parent. Now they are at the center, but it looks quite weird. I should reduce their position about half their size but it is possible only in CSS? I don't want to engage JS for it, because code will be illegible.

**CSS**

```
.handle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    border: black 1px solid
}
.handle#top {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}

.handle#left {
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.handle#right {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.handle#bottom {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="object">
    <div class="handle" id="left"></div>
    <div class="handle" id="right"></div>
    <div class="handle" id="top"></div>
    <div class="handle" id="bottom"></div>
    <img src="svg/test1.svg" class="stopro"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `width: 1em;` and `height: 1em;` so when you use `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` also, deduct the margins using `margin-top` and `margin-left` which are equal to 1/2 of the total `height` and `width` of the element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3fPU/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/u3fPU/1/)

```
.handle#top {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -.5em;
}

.handle#left {
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}

.handle#right {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}

.handle#bottom {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -.5em;
}
```

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't have his image but I don't need demo, I am confident with my code :)

Comment: but what if I wanted to change size of my ".handle"? I would have to change all of "margin" ones.

Comment: @Ludwik11 you need to change the margins as well than

Comment: it is not much convenient. Are there any mathematical operations in CSS?

Comment: @NoobEditor added demo

Comment: @Ludwik11 no, you cannot calculate using CSS, you will have to use jQuery than... or use pre processors like SASS or LESS

Comment: hmm, it seems like I haven't any choice :/ I have to use JS

Comment: @Ludwik11 but I wouldn't suggest you to use JS if you are not going to change the dimensions often

Comment: @Ludwik11: If you want to change the size of the handles you need to change two values in your CSS anyway. Is it really that much more work to change four more values at the same time? Stick with CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot your stuff - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949848/border-shadow-isssue/20949930#comment31464901_20949922

Comment: He stole an answer that isn't even relevant to the question. Oh dear.

Comment: @thirtydot I was just commenting that, this isn't even relevant, and I got the red box that the answer may be deleted :D