# Border shadow issue

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue to add a box-shadow only on left and right on multiple divs.

I have tried this method already. [This is an
example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/) of what I want, but it only works for a single div and did not help me out.

My code has several main blocks. I.e.

```
<div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
 <div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

I need to add box shadow to main block css code

```
.main:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    left: -15px;
}
.main:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    right: -15px;
}
.main {   width: 980px; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; background:#fff; padding: 0 25px; }
```

Wrapper has full width.

Comment: I see the shadow only on the left and the right of your `div` in your fiddle, what is the issue?

Comment: that fiddle is not the one which is mine i tried that fiddle but it did not work with for my above code.

Comment: They are saying that the example fiddle doesn't work with their implementation.

Comment: @damien you are right.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with your own setup?

Comment: You have no "content" and "position" declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's too much mess, why not try this? I just got rid of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo as well..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/228/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/229/) (Multiple elements)

```
div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0px 0px #eee, 
                0 -10px 0px 0px #eee, 
                10px 0 13px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
                -10px 0 13px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: @Damien I don't understand him anyways, I just refactored the code

Comment: @Damien He had to simply replicate the elements, that's it :) I made his 24 line CSS to 8 line

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

## **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/227/)**

CSS

```
.main:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
.main:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
}
.main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
div{margin: 20px; width: 400px; height: 400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 2px  #222,  -4px 0 2px #222;   
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222;   
box-shadow: 4px 0 2px #222,  -4px 0 2px #222; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepak_datwani/Qq5tQ/230/)